# MYSQL Query optimization, comparing 3 tables w/ thousands of records

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have this query:

```
SELECT L.sku,L.desc1,M.map,T.retail FROM listing L INNER JOIN moto M ON L.sku=M.sku INNER JOIN truck T ON L.sku=T.sku LIMIT 5;
```

Each table (listing,moto,truck) has ~300.000 rows, and just for testing purppose i've set a LIMIT of 5 results, at the end i will need hundreds but let see...

That query takes like 3:26 minutes in Console...i wont imagine how much it will take with PHP...i need to handle it there

Any advice/solution to Optmize the query? Thanks!

Comment: optimizing depends on table structure. but Joining in query is surely expensive thing. plz try to avoid join and find if there is any other option available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to recommend here:

- Indexes
- Denormalization

One thing people tend to do when databases get massive is invoke **Denormalization**. This is when you store the data from multiple tables in one table to prevent the need to do a `join`. This is useful if your application relies on specific reads to power it. It is a commonly used tactic when scaling.

If `Denormalization` is out of the question, another, simpler way to optimize this query would be to make sure you have **indexes** on the columns you are running the `join` against. So the columns `L.sku`, `m.sku`,`T.sku` would need to be indexed, you will immediately notice an increase in performance.

Any other optimizations I would need some more information about the data, hope it helps!

Comment: i was use to work with small databases, so i've never used INDEXES, now i did and it took less than a second :) thx